# Laravel Complex Eloquest Query with paginate

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I' developing an app using google map where user search for a location and then it returns places in a specific radius. But I got stuck in how to write down the code in Eloquent. My query is :

```
$lat    = $request->input( 'lat' );
$lng    = $request->input( 'lng' );
$dist   = $request->input( 'dist' );

$query  = "SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations WHERE lat != '$lat' AND lng != '$lng' HAVING distance <= $dist ORDER BY id DESC";
```

I've tried :

```
   $locations = \DB::table( 'locations' )->select(['*', "( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) as distance"])->paginate(5);
```

But it seems it is not working. Instead it displays this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from `locations` limit 5 offset 0' at line 1 (SQL: select *, `(` as * from `locations` limit 5 offset 0)
```

Please help me figure out the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just pass your SQL Query in a `DB::select()` method for example:

```
DB::select("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations WHERE lat != '$lat' AND lng != '$lng' HAVING distance <= $dist ORDER BY id DESC")->paginate(5);
```

References:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-convert-google-map-sql-query-as-laravel-query

Comment: Then how can I apply paginate() in this method ? It is throwing error : Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: I made it work by using the following :

\DB::table( 'locations' )
                    ->select(\DB::raw( "*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance" ))
                    ->paginate('2');

Comment: sorry for late reply, so it is working now? okay sorry I just haven't test it with your case.

Comment: The query i just posted is working with the condition of the distance. But when I add the distance condition is breaks again. The condition I tried is as  follows : 

\DB::table( 'locations' )
                    ->select(\DB::raw( "*,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance" ))
                    ->where( 'lat', '!=', "'$lat'" )
                    ->where( 'lng', '!=', "'$lng'" )
                    ->having( 'distance', '<=', "$dist" )
                    ->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [raw db](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects) query injection, so it won't be processed and corrupted by Laravel:
    select(
        Db::raw(
            "*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) as distance"
        )
    )

Maybe it makes sense to validate and precalculate `radians('$lat')` and `radians('$lng')`

As an option you can select all the `id, lat, lon`, calculate distances in your script with some function, filter ids by distance and then select that records from db. It will be more readable.

Also you can create a stored MySQL function to make these calculations.

The latter two ways provide let you test, if you distance calculation function works correctly.